# Java Spring Framework, What is best practice, XML File or Bean for Populating Bread Crumbs in JSP Page

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Java and JSP. I have found information on this topic but some is rather dated so I was hoping to get a more current response.

My thought was to have a XML file set up like the following and based on the name attribute grab the info for that bread crumb.

```
 <root>
      <view name="x">
           <crumb>
                <value1></value1>
                <value2></value2>
           </crumb>
           <crumb>
                 <value1></value1>
                 <value2></value2>
           </crumb>
     </view>
     <view name="y">
           <crumb>
                <value1></value1>
                <value2></value2>
           </crumb>
           <crumb>
                <value1></value1>
                <value2></value2>
           </crumb>
      </view>
 </root>
```

Is the Spring BeanFactory the best option or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various configurations for the bean.xml file I have come to this solution for my needs. I'm sharing this resolution in hopes it may help someone with similar needs. If anyone recognizes a cause for concern with server resources or pages being served slowly, and know of a better way, please share.

I configured the beans.xml like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="viewName" class="com.mycompany.beans.BreadCrumbs">
      <property name="crumbList">
          <list>
              <value>Home</value>
              <value>Admin</value>
          </list>
      </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="Home" class="com.mycompany.beans.BreadCrumbs">
      <property name="prop1" value="value1"/>
      <property name="prop2" value="value2"/>
  </bean>   

  <bean id="Admin" class="com.mycompany.beans.BreadCrumbs">
      <property name="prop1" value="value1"/>
      <property name="prop2" value="value2"/>
  </bean>
```

The class method that parses the bean.xml is as follows.

```
 public String crumb(String viewName){

    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("breadCrumb.xml");
    BreadCrumbs crumbListObj = (BreadCrumbs) appContext.getBean(viewName);

    List y = crumbListObj.getCrumbList();
    String x="";

    for (int i=0; i < y.size(); i++){

      BreadCrumbs crumbpropsObj = (BreadCrumbs) appContext.getBean("" + y.get(i) + "");
      if (x.length() > 0){x += ",";}
      x = x + "," + y.get(i) + "," + crumbpropsObj.getVaule1() + "," + crumbpropsObj.getValue2(); 

    }

    return x;

 }
```